# Incorrect calculation of line height

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing a set of attributes to find out the height of the text stored in UILabel.
For a line with plain text this was done, but I can not calculate the header.
The problem is that the header is displayed in large letters and the length is calculated for the regular line.

The string to be calculated:
Here's the code:

```
    if let feed = self.datasource?.item(indexPath) as? Feed{
    let approximateWidthOfTitlePost = view.frame.width - 15 - 15
    let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfTitlePost, height: 1000)
    let attributeShortContent = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]

    let attributeTitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]


    let estimatedFrameContent = NSString(string: feed.shortContentPost).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeShortContent, context: nil)

    let estimatedFrameTitle = NSString(string: feed.titlePost).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)
```

The wrong value is obtained in `estimatedFrameTitle.height`
To display capital letters, use `.uppercased()`

Comment: Are you doing things using Auto Layout?

Comment: No, I do not use Auto Layout

Comment: It will be good if you work with Auto Layout on such kind of task @WaterKill

Answer (score 0):

> You have just need to add .uppercased() in estimatedFrameTitle &
>   estimatedFrameContent

```
       if let feed = self.datasource?.item(indexPath) as? Feed {
            let approximateWidthOfTitlePost = view.frame.width - 15 - 15
            let size = CGSize(width: approximateWidthOfTitlePost, height: 1000)

            let attributeShortContent = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
            let attributeTitle = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]

            let estimatedFrameContent = NSString(string: feed.shortContentPost.uppercased()).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeShortContent, context: nil)
            let estimatedFrameTitle = NSString(string: feed.titlePost.uppercased()).boundingRect(with: size, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attributeTitle, context: nil)
        }
```